# How to download and open XML file via SFTP?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sftp, ssh.net

I need to open XML file (create XmlDocument) without creating local copy. Using SSH.NET, I came up with this code:

```
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("host",
    "username",
    new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username", "password"));

using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();

    System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    client.DownloadFile("filename.xml", mem);

    mem.Position=0;

    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mem))
    {
        var docc = new XmlDocument();
        docc.Load(mem);
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

But is gets stuck on `docc.Load(mem)`. What could be the problem?

`mem` object looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Note that your `XmlReader` is not used. Either do `docc.Load(reader);` or remove xml reader at all.

Comment: @Evk that was a really stupid mistake from my side, changing to `docc.Load(reader)` fixed the issue. Please post as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that here:

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mem))
{
    var docc = new XmlDocument();
    docc.Load(mem);
}
```

You are not using variable `reader` at all. Either change to

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mem))
{
    var docc = new XmlDocument();
    docc.Load(reader);
}
```

or remove reader at all:

```
docc.Load(mem);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by @Evk solves your immediate problem, your code is still inefficient.

Use `SftpClient.OpenRead` to directly stream the file to `XmlReader`:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(client.OpenRead("filename.xml"))
{
    // process the XML
}
```

or to `XmlDocument`:

```
var docc = new XmlDocument();
docc.Load(client.OpenRead("filename.xml"));
```

This way, you do not waste a memory by creating another copy of the file in `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wrote xml file to stream and now, stream is pointed at the end of xml file. Try setting stream.position to 0 before loading.

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();

    System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    client.DownloadFile("filename.xml", mem);
    // Set stream position
    mem.Position = 0;
    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mem))
    {
        var docc = new XmlDocument();
        docc.Load(mem);
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

I would also change the code to dispose the memory stream correctly...

Comment: Is there any data in the stream? What's its length?

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze Position  is not 0. Have you set it?